# Postgres Layer not showing as editable when creating an offline project

Tags: qgis-plugins

My postgres layer in a QGIS saved project does not appear in the `"Creat Offline Project"` dialog as editable.  I want to check it out for offline editing?  If I uncheck the `"Show only editable layers"` box, it then appears.

It checks out fine but edits cannot be saved in the remote session.

Comment: Can you edit the layer when you are online? Do the user you connect with have write access to the table?

Comment: I have no trouble editing while online at all and I am the user/admin trying to create the offline project SQLITE file.